# Автоматический парсинг текстовых таблиц

Tags: python

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs   16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.2G  1.1M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/vda1      ext4      388G  230G  159G  60% /
```

Есть ли какие-то решения для автоматической конвертации чего-то подобного в список словарей, например?

```
[
    {
        "filesystem": "udev",
        "type": "devtmpfs",
        "size": "16G",
        "used": "0"
        ...
    },
    {
        "filesystem": "tmpfs",
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: И да поможет вам pandas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Колонки в вашем файле имеют фиксированную ширину, поэтому удобно использовать специально предусмотренную для таких случаев функцию [`pd.read_fwf()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) ***f**ixed-**w**idth **f**ormatted* c аргументом `widths=` (или `colspecs=`):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf(r'c:\test\sample.txt', widths=[15, 10, 6, 5, 6, 5, 100])
print(df.to_json(orient='records', indent=2)) # или df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

```
[
  {
    "Filesystem":"udev",
    "Type":"devtmpfs",
    "Size":"16G",
    "Used":"0",
    "Avail":"16G",
    "Use%":"0%",
    "Mounted on":"\/dev"
  },
  {
    "Filesystem":"tmpfs",
    "Type":"tmpfs",
    "Size":"3.2G",
    "Used":"1.1M",
    "Avail":"3.2G",
    "Use%":"1%",
    "Mounted on":"\/run"
  },
  {
    "Filesystem":"\/dev\/vda1",
    "Type":"ext4",
    "Size":"388G",
    "Used":"230G",
    "Avail":"159G",
    "Use%":"60%",
    "Mounted on":"\/"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Используйте pandas и читайте файл как csv. Обратите внимание, что в этом примере pandas сам разбивает на колонки по пробелам, поэтому приходится еще вручную удалять и переименовывать колонки (колонку "Mounted on" pandas посчитает за две отдельных:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("2.txt", sep="\s+")
df = df.rename(columns={"Mounted":"Mounted_on"})
df = df.drop(columns=["on"])
res = df.to_dict("records")
print(res)
```

> [{'Filesystem': 'udev', 'Type': 'devtmpfs', 'Size': '16G', 'Used': '0', 'Avail': '16G', 'Use%': '0%', 'Mounted_on': '/dev'}, {'Filesystem': 'tmpfs', 'Type': 'tmpfs', 'Size': '3.2G', 'Used': '1.1M', 'Avail': '3.2G', 'Use%': '1%', 'Mounted_on': '/run'}, {'Filesystem': '/dev/vda1', 'Type': 'ext4', 'Size': '388G', 'Used': '230G', 'Avail': '159G', 'Use%': '60%', 'Mounted_on': '/'}]

Answer (score 1):

```
txt = "Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on\n" \
      "udev           devtmpfs   16G     0   16G   0% /dev\n" \
      "tmpfs          tmpfs     3.2G  1.1M  3.2G   1% /run\n" \
      "\n" \
      "/dev/vda1      ext4      388G  230G  159G  60% /\n"
txt = txt.replace('Mounted on', 'Mounted_on')
k, *d = [x.split() for x in txt.splitlines() if x]
aa = [{kk.lower(): xx for kk, xx in zip(k, x)} for x in d]
print(aa)

txt = "Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on " \
      "udev           devtmpfs   16G     0   16G   0% /dev " \
      "tmpfs          tmpfs     3.2G  1.1M  3.2G   1% /run " \
      "/dev/vda1      ext4      388G  230G  159G  60% / "
txt = txt.replace('Mounted on', 'Mounted_on')
baz = txt.split()
n = 7
k, *d = [baz[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(baz), n)]
aa = [{kk.lower(): xx for kk, xx in zip(k, x)} for x in d]
print(aa)
```